# GPS waypoint mapping with android phone

Tags: kml, gps, android, gpx

I am a bat enthusiast and volunteer regularly with the local bat groups on bat surveys. In them we record bats with a bat detector - making a note of the different species (there are 18 in the UK), the activity and its location on a map (which can be inaccurate). Once home I will then take this information and on word put different coloured dots (depending on the species) on a digital map to be sent away to be filed. I was wondering if there a way to do the recording part on my android phone.

I've downloaded various waypoint recording app which give me a gpx or kml file. With this i need a mapping system that can take this information and lay it onto a chosen map. also, the program needs to be able to distinguish between the various colours (species) and these colours need to show up on the map. Also, if there are more than one species recorded on the same location the dot needs to be twice its size. so to reiterate the program needs to give me flexibility to modify what the dots look like.

hope someone can help.

thanks.

Comment: Are you actually looking for an Android-based mapping program to display your GPS data, or just a program (any specific operating system?) to map the GPS waypoints that came FROM your Android app?

Comment: UK Android App called 'Record Wildlife'  does this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.record.wild.life&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/). 
See [Mapping GPS point using QGIS](http://courses.umass.edu/nrc297s/PDFs/Mapping_GPS_points_using_QGIS.pdf), for loading the GPS point the easiest way is to use [GPS tools plugin](http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/The_GPS_tools_plugin).

For editing the labels:
I think you should write the bat specie as a comment of your GPS data log.
In QGIS you have to open the properties of the vector layer go to Style and than you can specify the color of your label depending on the attribute (e.g. comment ( bat specie)) using [categorized](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-styling-vector-data-in-qgis.html).